# edit certain lines in txt file php

Tags: php, file, text

I have a config file that I edit on my mobile while I'm not at home, just one file. It has 30 lines, but I only want to edit lines 9-14. Lately I have just been opening the whole file and finding the lines and editing it. Would like to make it a bit easier on the mobile.

Also can you have each line in its own textbox?

```
 <?php
// set file to read
$filename = "ALLPAIRS-params.js";

$newdata = $_POST['newd'];

if ($newdata != '') {

// open file 
$fw = fopen($filename, 'w') or die('Could not open file!');
// write to file
// added stripslashes to $newdata
$fb = fwrite($fw,stripslashes($newdata)) or die('Could not write 
to file');
// close file
fclose($fw);
}

// open file
  $fh = fopen($filename, "r") or die("Could not open file!");
// read file contents
  $data = fread($fh, filesize($filename)) or die("Could not read file!");
// close file
  fclose($fh);
// print file contents
 echo "<h3>Contents of File</h3>
<form action='$_SERVER[php_self]' method= 'post' >
<textarea name='newd' cols='100%' rows='50'> $data </textarea>
<input type='submit' value='Change'>
</form>";

?>
```

Comment: Use `file()` function of php with flag `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES`. it will convert each line of your file into array values. Now you can iterate over this array and show each value into text-box or you can easilly change 9-14 line by using `$array[9] = 'something new'....so on;`.And after that use `implode()` with `"\n"` to make this array as string with new-lines and then use `file_put_contents()` method to save this new data to file

Comment: It looks like your config file is JS, so is it just a JS object, like JSON? If so, it would be super easy to revise. You'd just create a simple form, post the values to a script that json_encodes them, and then overwrites the file.